# Compute Portfolio Variance in R with covariance matrix in stacked format in dataframe

Tags: r, variance, portfolio

I have my cov matrix and weights in 2 separate dataframes and I would like to compute portfolio variance (for each portfolio at each date, my example only has 1 portfolio and 2 dates for simplicity):

```
weights <- data.frame(Portfolio = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1", "P1"),
    Date = c("2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-06-30", "2008-06-30", "2008-06-30"),
    ID = c("Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3"),
    Wgt = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1))


covar <- data.frame(
    Date = c("2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31",
        "2008-06-30", "2008-06-30", "2008-06-30", "2008-06-30", "2008-06-30", "2008-06-30", "2008-06-30", "2008-06-30", "2008-06-30"),
    ID1 = c("Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3",
        "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3"),
    ID2 = c("Asset1", "Asset1", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset2", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset3", "Asset3",
        "Asset1", "Asset1", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset2", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset3", "Asset3"),
    cov = c(0.011,      0.012,   0.013,    0.012,   0.022,     0.032,     0.013,     0.032,     0.033,
             0.0011,      0.0012,   0.0013,    0.0012,   0.0022,     0.0032,     0.0013,     0.0032,     0.0033)
)
```

Comment: So do you want to add another column to your `covar` data frame that has the variance for P1?

Comment: ideally I would like it added to weights dataframe. So that I know for each portolio and date what the corresponding variance was. This would mean the same value would be repeated then, since I have as many rows for each portfolio as I have weights. But it could also be part of a new dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to reshape the data into a form that is more natural (and more efficient) for the computations; you can do this with `?tapply`:

```
## <your data>
weights <- data.frame(Portfolio = c("P1", "P1", "P1"),
                      Date = c("2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31"),
                      ID = c("Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3"),
                      Wgt = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3))


covar <- data.frame(
    Date = c("2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31"),
    ID1 = c("Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3"),
    ID2 = c("Asset1", "Asset1", "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset2", "Asset2", "Asset3", "Asset3", "Asset3"),
    cov = c(0.011,      0.012,   0.013,    0.012,   0.022,     0.032,     0.013,     0.032,     0.033)
)
```

Create covariance matrices for all dates:

```
C <- covm <- tapply(covar$cov, covar[, c("ID1", "ID2", "Date")], c)
## , , Date = 2008-03-31
## 
##         ID2
## ID1      Asset1 Asset2 Asset3
##   Asset1  0.011  0.012  0.013
##   Asset2  0.012  0.022  0.032
##   Asset3  0.013  0.032  0.033
```

Create portfolios for all dates:

```
W <- tapply(weights$Wgt, list(weights$ID, weights$Portfolio, weights$Date), c,
            default = 0)
## , , 2008-03-31
## 
##         P1
## Asset1 0.1
## Asset2 0.2
## Asset3 0.3
```

Now you could loop over the dates and compute what
you'd need. For variance and a specific date:

```
W[,, "2008-03-31"] %*% C[,, "2008-03-31"] %*% W[,, "2008-03-31"]

##         [,1]
## [1,] 0.00906
```

An equivalent computation is this one (taken from [Vectorised objective functions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMOF/vignettes/vectorise.pdf)):

```
colSums(C[,, "2008-03-31"] %*% W[,, "2008-03-31"] * W[,, "2008-03-31"])
## [1] 0.00906
```

This second formulation is useful when you have more
than one portfolio for a given date. For instance:

```
weights <- data.frame(Portfolio = c("P1", "P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2"),
                      Date = c("2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31",
                               "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31", "2008-03-31"),
                      ID = c("Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3",
                             "Asset1", "Asset2", "Asset3"),
                      Wgt = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.1))
##   Portfolio       Date     ID Wgt
## 1        P1 2008-03-31 Asset1 0.1
## 2        P1 2008-03-31 Asset2 0.2
## 3        P1 2008-03-31 Asset3 0.3
## 4        P2 2008-03-31 Asset1 0.5
## 5        P2 2008-03-31 Asset2 0.4
## 6        P2 2008-03-31 Asset3 0.1

## (same code as above)
W <- tapply(weights$Wgt, list(weights$ID, weights$Portfolio, weights$Date), c,
            default = 0)

Now the portfolios are columns:

## , , 2008-03-31
## 
##         P1  P2
## Asset1 0.1 0.5
## Asset2 0.2 0.4
## Asset3 0.3 0.1


colSums(C[,, "2008-03-31"] %*% W[,, "2008-03-31"] * W[,, "2008-03-31"])
##      P1      P2 
## 0.00906 0.01526
```

There are many details you'll need to check: do all
portfolios hold the same assets, are there data for
every calendar date, missing values, ...

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this Enrico. Is there a way to do this without using a loop? With say group_by?

Comment: So this works on the small dataset, but on my large dataset the tapply causes my computer to crash. Is there maybe a different way to do this?

Comment: I was able to make it work by doing it chunk wise.

Comment: I am still having issues with this once I switch to my actual covariance matrix as there seem to be strange values in the dataframe, such as "numeric23", not sure what is happening there.

Comment: So this works for the min example but for my actual covariance dataframe for some reason the values are changed like I said to strange values such as "numeric23"

Comment: `group_by`: sorry, I don't use `dplyr`. Crash: your computer crashes? Or R? Or does it become unresponsive? The code above computes all covariance matrices, so if you have many dates & many assets, this might too much memory for your machine. Regarding the "numeric23": could you identify a date when this happens, and post an example how the data looks then?

Comment: I will try to reproduce the error with a small example to get an idea where the numeric23 is coming from. The crashing occurred on a smaller computer with the entire dataset, but I was able to filter out some unnecessary rows and switch to a bigger computer. I am happy to do it without dplyr with this loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you would need to group by `Portfolio` and `Date` and create a new column that calculates the variance of the `Wgt` column.

```
library(dplyr)

P_Variance <- weights %>% 
  group_by(Portfolio, Date) %>% 
  mutate(Var = var(Wgt))
```

```
> P_Variance
# A tibble: 3 × 5
# Groups:   Portfolio, Date [1]
  Portfolio Date       ID       Wgt   Var
  <chr>     <chr>      <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 P1        2008-03-31 Asset1   0.1  0.01
2 P1        2008-03-31 Asset2   0.2  0.01
3 P1        2008-03-31 Asset3   0.3  0.01
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: not quite. You are correct about the group by but the portfolio variance is computed by multipliying the transpose of the weights vector times the covarince matrix times the weights vector. So somewhere in the mutate, I need to get this calculation in.

Answer (score 0):

I still have not figured this out but I was able to get it work for 1 single date and 1 single portfolio. Maybe if someone knows how to do this for all the dates and all portfolios? That is, I somehow need to find a way to do combine the summarize command with the groupby so I can run it for one date and one portfolio at a time.

```
# Merge data frames
merged_data <- merge(weights, covar, by.x = c("Date", "ID"), by.y = c("Date", "ID1"))

cov_matrix <- merged_data %>% filter(Portfolio=='P1',Date=="2008-03-31") %>% select( "Date", "ID",  "ID2" , "cov") %>%  tidyr::spread(key = ID2, value = cov) %>%
    select(-ID, -Date) %>%
    as.matrix()

weights_vector <- merged_data %>% filter(Portfolio=='P1',Date=="2008-03-31", ID==ID2)  %>% select( "Wgt") %>%    as.matrix()

# Calculate portfolio variance using matrix multiplication
portfolio_variances <- merged_data %>%
    group_by(Portfolio, Date)    %>% summarise(portfolio_variance = t(weights_vector)  %*% cov_matrix %*% weights_vector)
```